# Word for a lighthouse enthusiast

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I'm fairly certain I've heard/seen a word to describe someone who likes or studies lighthouses, similar to audiophile for someone who likes music. Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: ............Ray

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As expected, I didn't find it in OED, but I've no doubt most such people would understand and accept the designation ***pharologist***, derived from...

> **pharology** *- the scientific study of lighthouses and signal lights.*

---

EDIT: I broke off for my tea earlier, before getting around to checking other online resources. I still can't find a *current dictionary definition*, but I see [Wikipedia says...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharology)

> *Those who study or are enthused by lighthouses are known as **pharologists***

...and Collins dictionary has the word filed under ["Pending Investigation"](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/10982/Pharologist)

As regards actual usage, it's worth noting that Google Books claims 970 instances of [pharologist](https://www.google.com/search?q=pharologist&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), and another 48 for [the plural](https://www.google.com/search?q=pharologist&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=pharologists&tbm=bks) (for comparison, they have 3 hits for [pharophile](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pharophile%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) and 1 [pharophiles](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pharophile%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22pharophiles%22&tbm=bks)).

---

If anyone wants the etymological background that told me what to look for, this is from OED...

> ***pharos*** - classical Latin *pharos, pharus* lighthouse, spec. (as proper name) the lighthouse on the island of *Pharos* built for Ptolemy II of Egypt, in post-classical Latin also lamp, candelabrum (5th cent.) < *Pharos , Pharus* (ancient Greek *Φάρος&*), the name of an island off Alexandria (now a peninsula forming part of the city); compare Hellenistic Greek *ϕάρος* lighthouse.

Personally I'd say that makes it essentially *Greek* rather than *Latin* origin, but others may disagree.

Comment: "Phare" is the French, and probably Latin word for Lighthouse, so this makes sense.

Comment: @Tom: I only knew what to search for in the first place because of the ancient Greek lighthouse on Pharos. Having checked the etymology I'm now unsure whether to say the "origin" is Greek or Latin. So I'll amend the answer to include what seems relevant from OED - if anyone's interested, they can make their own decision starting from that information.

Comment: @Fumble: As you mentioned about my answer then I'm going to talk about yours. First of all, you should check the number of Google result carefully, Google doesn't reveal the actual number till the last result and it mixes up with "pharology" if you don't put the word in quotes. Actual result for pharaologist is [23(?)](https://www.google.com/search?q=pharologist&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22pharologist%22&safe=off&start=20&tbm=bks). In the end, both pharologist an pharophile is not that common. [to be continued]

Comment: Secondly, using pharologist for both the enthusiast and the one who studies it scientifically is a bit confusing. I don't know why some sources mention that and how it turned out that way. Pharophile makes more sense for the enthusiast. For example, there is a difference between audiophile and audiologist also.

Comment: Darn this 5 min comment editing rule. I meant result for "pharologist"  (not pharaologist).

Comment: @ermanen, such a pattern can be confusing, but it is still is found, with e.g. *ornithologist* covering the amateur birdwatcher and the professional researcher. In the days of the gentleman scientist, such a distinction was less rigid in any case, which perhaps had an effect.

Comment: @ermanen: I didn't intend my revision to be seen as a reaction to your answer. I really did break off to eat after posting *pharologist* - at which time I had every intention of mentioning *pharophile*, for exactly the reasons you've given. For reasons that escape me, GB is sensitive to whether single-word search terns are "quotated", *and* it lists many results where you can't actually *see* the search word, so they may be lies anyway. In fact, I only saw ***10*** actual instances of the word *pharologist* in my results (and 1 *pharophile*), but it was still claiming 797 hits after 20 pages.

Comment: @Jon: I think, that sense is a bit different than this. It is about birdwatching and amateur science. How about if you are enthusiastic about birds in general? Though ornithophilia comes to mind but it is a bit risky word and it is used in botany also. Maybe it is better to say "bird enthusiast". So in the end, there is this confusion about meanings that -logist cover.

Comment: @Fumble: Then I'm helping you I guess :) I'm not saying your answer is wrong also. But we couldn't be sure about the right answer because of the lack of sources.

Comment: @ermanen: To be honest, I don't think there is a "right answer" here. OP asked for *a word to describe someone who **likes** or **studies** lighthouses*. I'm sure most people would agree ***-phile = one who likes***, and ***-ologist = one who studies***. Personally, I'd say I'm an *audiophile*, but I'm certainly not an *audiologist*. I suppose if OP would like to clarify exactly what *he* is thinking of, we might be better able to say one of our two offerings is better than the other. But the key point is *any* credible answer more or less *has* to be a derivative of ***pharos***.

Answer (score 6):

There is a neologism: ***pharophile***. It is not a common word and it is not in dictionaries. But it is used colloquially.

This word applies to both who likes and studies lighthouses.

For example, this word is used in an [Australian website about lighthouses](http://www.lighthouses.org.au/lights/Bulletin/0505/pharology_101.htm):

> We begin a series of "lessons" for **lighthouse buffs (pharophiles**) on lighthouse technology, physics and chemistry, as written and researched by our LoA Inc President, Denise Shultz, who in a former life was a chemical engineer. This first part of Pharology 101 discusses the mercury float, which was originally used in most lighthouses around the world to support and rotate the lens.

Comment: I'm not sure “colloquially” is the best word to describe the usage sphere of _pharophile_. Colloquially, I'd expect the other word (_lighthouse buff_) to be far more common.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: But the entire "buff" thing is quite localised

Comment: @Light How so? _Buff_ is used in this sense in both AmE, BrE, and AuE (and probably lots more). Hardly localised. But my point was just that in an informal, colloquial chat, _pharophile_ is not a word I'd expect to hear.

Comment: I meant colloquially among lighthouse enthusiasts. "lighthouse enthusiast" is more common also but we were looking for a single word.